# Impact of empty commit

Tags: git

In my team the process to backport changes from `master` to a release branch includes a last step of checking out master and doing a merge from the release branch to master (this is after cherry-picking the fix from master). This merge is supposed to be empty and is meant to "keep the history". I don't understand what is the goal of this empty commit. Can someone explain? is it just for a human to have a "bookmark" of when things were cherry-picked or there really is a difference in git behaviour if we don't do that empty commit?

The process looks like this

1. fix bug in topic branch and merge it via a pull request to `master`. Note the merge sha1
2. check out release branch `git checkout release/v1`
3. cherry pick the fix `git cherry-pick -m 1 <merge-sha>`
4. push release branch with newly picked fix
5. checkout master
6. `git pull && git merge release/v1` //this is what I don't understand
7. verify commit is empty
8. `git push`

Comment: I kinda see what they are thinking... If you do a cherry-pick of a commit and apply it to the feature branch, you have no record of that (You don't know from where the commit is coming). If you later merge from feature to master, you can see the connection between the cherry-picked commit and the master branch (where it was or is)

Comment: Perhaps it will also serve as confirmation that no unwanted or unexpected changes were included in error (step #7 !!)

Answer (score 0):

It records the merge. All commits from the release branch are then part of master too. Otherwise, you would have two diverged branches.

Comment: i don't understand. all commits should happen in master first and cherry picked to release second. this guarantees that fixes are in both. if there are commits only in release they should not be part of master because they are release-specific.
in any case, isn't a release branch divergent from master by design??

Comment: By (re-)merging the release branch into master, you are making sure that no "accidental" changes end up in the release branch. ALL changes of the release branch are then present in master too.